# Which Option gives the best performance with pyspark ? An UDF or RDD processing with map?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, spark-structured-streaming

Which Option gives the best performance with pyspark ? A UDF or RDD processing with a map ?

I'm consuming data with spark Structured streaming and for every micro-batch, I'm converting DF to RDD  and doing some python graphkit operations and converting again RDD to DF to write to Kafka stream.

Answer (score 2):

I have generally observed that udf is faster than rdd mapping. Depending on your python version, you can use pandas udf, that is definitely faster. Refer here : https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html

Comment: I understood pandas udf is faster. but when you convert spark df to pandas df then it takes data to driver node. I feel its not a distributed computing.

Comment: You don't need to convert it to pandas. Refer the example in the link
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
    # Use pandas_udf to define a Pandas UDF
    @pandas_udf('double', PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
    # Input/output are both a pandas.Series of doubles
    def pandas_plus_one(v):
        return v + 1
    df.withColumn('v2', pandas_plus_one(df.v))

So the pandas udf can be directly applied to spark dataframes. The name pandas udf , because rather than row by row execution, our column is processes as a pandas series or pandas dataframe based on the function type